# css positioned element offscreen but scrollbar persist

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a DIV off the screen so that I can use `JQuery Animations` to "slide" multiple DIVs on\off the screen (horizontally)...  However I'm having trouble positioning the 2nd DIV as it's creating scroll bars even though it has a negative top margin.

All elements are positioned relatively (and maybe that's my problem?).  The 1st main DIV that is being slid off is positioned in the center with `margin:auto` and has a top offset to help center it vertically as well.

The 2nd DIV has `right:5000` to move it off screen. but since it's in normal flow it still causes vertical scroll bars, even with `top:-10000`  I've tried `overflow:hidden` with no luck, not sure what else to do.  (I don't want to completely disable scroll bars in case the dynamic content grows).

**Sample CSS**

```
#maincontent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:black;
}

#maincontent2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color:blue;
    top: -1000px
}

body{
    position:relative;
}
```

**Sample HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="maincontent"></div>
   <div id="maincontent2"></div>
</body>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with a dumbed down version of what I'm working with. [Sample JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkLqv29p/)

This seems like it should be extremely simple but maybe I'be been working too long on this today and have overlooked something when searching.

**BONUS**  If anyone has suggestions for another way to make this happen (DIVs sliding off screen and another one taking it's place) that works too!

Comment: Relative positioning remains the space that the element occupies as if it is not positioned. Therefore, absolute positioning should be use instead.

Comment: but don't I lose the ability to center the DIV automatically?  Or should I just position the "offscreen" div as absolute while it's offscreen... and when I move it onscreen change the position type at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

It's Very simple Just add

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Or

Add a Parent level div and Write `overflow-x:hidden`  to that div

Comment: from the OP: "(I don't want to completely disable scroll bars in case the dynamic content grows)."

Comment: parent to the offscreen or onscreen div?

Comment: You can use absolute or relative but off screen should Appear scroll, so overflow property is must needed. instead of body you can use any parent level DIV(for Both)

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning occupies space as per the normal document flow. To take the element out of the document flow, use absolute positioning.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkLqv29p/2/

Edit the `top` property of `#maincontent2` to bring it back "down" into the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://codepen.io/nathanbirrell/pen/xGLXgB

This has a menu and everything setup with vertical animation.

The JS includes:

```js
$("span").click(function() {
  $("nav").toggleClass("active");
  $("li").toggleClass("active");
  if($(this).text() == "☰") {
    $(this).text("×");
  }
  else {
    $(this).text("☰");
  }
})
```

Comment: That solution is using `position: fixed` instead of `relative` or `absolute` to avoid scrollbars.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want, Check out the updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkLqv29p/1/)

```
<body>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
<div id="maincontent2"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontent {


    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:black;
  }
#maincontent2 {
   position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:blue;
    top: -100px
}
body{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I need to be centered horizontally on the page.  The div size will be dynamic.